# Delphi progressbar with two or more current values

Tags: delphi, user-interface, progress-bar

I want to make a kind of multi-color bar in my software. A kind of progressbar, but with two current values.

That's why I need it.
I have some "budget parts", and each one of them has its own limit (100$, 1000$ etc.)
I also have an editing form for adding new bills (and linking bills to budget parts).
In this editor I want to visually represent how full is a budget part, and how much price of current bill affects this budget part.

For example, the whole bar is 100$.
Green part means sum of prices across saved bills, for example 60$.
Yellow part means price of the current bill, which is not saved yet, for example 5$.

Like this: [image: multi-part progressbar]

Of course, values should be set dynamically.

Can you recommend me any components for drawing this (maybe some advanced progressbar, that can display more than one current value?)

Comment: That's about the easiest component in the world to draw. You just need a `Paint` method that paints a bounding rectangle and then fills the interior with your two colours. It's no a progress bar really, it's a gauge. I'm not sure I'd look for a third party component. I'd just paint it myself.

Comment: You can use `TGauge` component sources (from `..\source\Samples\Delphi\Gauges.pas` in Delphi installation folder) as a starting point to write your progressbar component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David suggests, just paint it yourself. Just about the same amount of trouble. Drop a `TImage` where you want your gauge and use something like this:

```
procedure PaintTwoColorGauge(const BackgroundColor, BorderColor, FirstGaugeColor, SecondGaugeColor: TColor; FirstGaugeValue, SecondGaugeValue, TotalValue: Integer; const Img: TImage);
var B: TBitmap;
    ImgWidth, G1Width, G2Width: Integer;
begin
  B := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    B.Width := Img.Width;
    B.Height := Img.Height;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackgroundColor;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
    B.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height));

    if TotalValue <> 0 then
    begin
      ImgWidth := B.Width - 2; // Don't account the width of the borders.
      G1Width := (FirstGaugeValue * ImgWidth) div TotalValue;
      G2Width := (SecondGaugeValue * ImgWidth) div TotalValue;
      if G1Width > ImgWidth then G1Width := ImgWidth; // Just in case
      if G2Width > ImgWidth then G2Width := ImgWidth;

      if G2Width > G1Width then
        begin
          B.Canvas.Brush.Color := SecondGaugeColor;
          B.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, G2Width, B.Height));

          B.Canvas.Brush.Color := FirstGaugeColor;
          B.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, G1Width, B.Height));
        end
      else
        begin
          B.Canvas.Brush.Color := FirstGaugeColor;
          B.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, G1Width, B.Height));

          B.Canvas.Brush.Color := SecondGaugeColor;
          B.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, G2Width, B.Height));
        end;

    end;

    B.Canvas.Pen.Color := BorderColor;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    B.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height);

    Img.Picture.Assign(B);

  finally B.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For example, here's what this code does to my 3 TImages (my images are intentionally shpaed as you see them):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintTwoColorGauge(clWhite, clBlack, clGreen, clYellow, 50, 55, 100, Image1);
  PaintTwoColorGauge(clWhite, clBlack, clGreen, clYellow, 50, 60, 100, Image2);
  PaintTwoColorGauge(clWhite, clBlack, clGreen, clYellow, 20, 60, 100, Image3);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: I would use a `TPaintBox` instead, or create a custom component derived from `TGraphicControl`. Either one will use fewer system resources than a `TImage`. You can still use the above logic, just use the component's own `Canvas` property instead, either in the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event or the overridden `TGraphicControl.Paint()` method.

Comment: @Remy I'm with you, but I'm sure Cosmin choose for `TImage` for ease of adoptation.

Comment: @NGLN TPaintBox is easier for this purpose than `TImage`. No temp bitmap needed.

Comment: @David Nor with `TImage`, which has a canvas you can draw to. I meant no need for storage of values and colors.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I think I'll adapt Cosmin's code for TPaintBox, as David and Remy suggested.
Thanks again!

Comment: @NGLN: `TImage` does not have its own `TCanvas` object. Yes, it has a `Canvas` property, but internally it merely forces the `TImage` to create a `TBitmap` inside of its `Picture` property and then delegates to it for drawing. `TPaintBox` and `TGraphicControl` have true `TCanvas` objects that draw directly to OS-provided onscreen `HDC`s instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,@NGLN: Anything that doesn't store the bitmap needs storage for the current setup of the gauge (colors,positions). Using `TImage` needs no such thing: you can drop a `TImage` on a form then call that single procedure with whatever values you've got. No need for secondary storage, no need for private field declarations. Not as efficient at runtime (because it stores a whole bitmap where only 7 fields might do) - but not exactly a problem. I specifically wrote this for the OP's question, but I'll probably apply this for my own code next time I feel the urge to write a tiny control.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own, it's fun! But while not really thát difficult, writing an own component could look like a daunting task. Especially for novice uses or without experience doing so.

Next in line of options is to draw it yourself, and the therefore intended component should "always" be the `TPaintBox` control. Implement the `OnPaint` event handler and it redraws itself when needed. Here an example implementation of how to transform such a paint box into a double gauge component:

```
type
  TDoubleGauge = record
    BackgroundColor: TColor;
    BorderColor: TColor;
    Color1: TColor;
    Color2: TColor;
    Value1: Integer;
    Value2: Integer;
    MaxValue: Integer;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDoubleGauge: TDoubleGauge;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Box: TPaintBox absolute Sender;
  MaxWidth: Integer;
  Width1: Integer;
  Width2: Integer;
begin
  with FDoubleGauge do
  begin
    Box.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackgroundColor;
    Box.Canvas.Pen.Color := BorderColor;
    Box.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, Box.Width, Box.Height);
    if MaxValue <> 0 then
    begin
      MaxWidth := Box.Width - 2;
      Width1 := (MaxWidth * Value1) div MaxValue;
      Width2 := (MaxWidth * Value2) div MaxValue;
      Box.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color2;
      if Abs(Value2) < Abs(MaxValue) then
        Box.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(1, 1, Width2, Box.Height - 1));
      Box.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color1;
      if Abs(Value1) < Abs(Value2) then
        Box.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(1, 1, Width1, Box.Height - 1));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDoubleGauge.BackgroundColor := clWhite;
  FDoubleGauge.BorderColor := clBlack;
  FDoubleGauge.Color1 := clGreen;
  FDoubleGauge.Color2 := clYellow;
  FDoubleGauge.Value1 := 50;
  FDoubleGauge.Value2 := 60;
  FDoubleGauge.MaxValue := 100;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;
```

Well, that looks like quite an effort. Especially when there are more of such doudble gauges needed on a single form. Therefore I like [Cosmin Prund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324943/757830), because he uses `TImage` components which are capable of "memorizing" what has to be redrawn when needed. Just as a bonus, here an alternative version of his code (with slightly different behaviour on invalid input):

```
procedure DrawDoubleGauge(BackgroundColor, BorderColor, Color1, Color2: TColor;
  Value1, Value2, MaxValue: Integer; Img: TImage);
var
  Width: Integer;
  Width1: Integer;
  Width2: Integer;
begin
  Img.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackgroundColor;
  Img.Canvas.Pen.Color := BorderColor;
  Img.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, Img.Width, Img.Height);
  if MaxValue <> 0 then
  begin
    Width := Img.Width - 2;
    Width1 := (Width * Value1) div MaxValue;
    Width2 := (Width * Value2) div MaxValue;
    Img.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color2;
    if Abs(Value2) < Abs(MaxValue) then
      Img.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(1, 1, Width2, Img.Height - 1));
    Img.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color1;
    if Abs(Value1) < Abs(Value2) then
      Img.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(1, 1, Width1, Img.Height - 1));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this exactly, as I don't want to spend any money on this I will follow the proposed solution, nevertheless if anyone would like an advanced component I found one that's not too expensive and look pretty decent in my opinion, here's the link in case it could be useful for someone else:

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advprogr.asp?s=

Thank's to all.